# web2py send value from a form to another controller

Tags: python, web2py

I'm trying to get value from user using form and send the value to another controller to do some operation on it

> Simple Example :
>   how to send x from (default/index.html) to (output/index.html)
>   or 
>   how to call the function (output/index) in (default/index.html)

```
default.py 
index(): 
return dict()

index.html 
{{extend 'layout.html'}} 
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{=URL()}}" method="post">
 Your name: <input name="name" /> <input type="submit" /> 
</form> 
{{x=request.vars.name}} 

output.py 
index(x): 
return x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just post the form to the URL that you want to handle the data:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{=URL('output', 'index')}}" method="post">
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I know it's stupid question but i'm new to web2py :)